# Access to UserProfile from ClaimProvider

Tags: user-profile-service, claim-provider

I try to access to UserProfile from FillClaimsForEntity.

```
protected override void FillClaimsForEntity(Uri context, SPClaim entity, List<SPClaim> claims)
{
    if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentException("entity");
    if (claims == null) throw new ArgumentException("claims");


    var userLoginEncoded = SPUtility.FormatAccountName("i", entity.Value);
    var userLogin = SPClaimProviderManager.Local.DecodeClaim(userLoginEncoded).Value;

    if (userLogin.IndexOf("nt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        return;
    }


    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
    {
        using (var site = new SPSite(context.ToString()))
        {
            var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I get this exception:

> 'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll but was not
>   handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No User Profile Application available to
>   service the request. Contact your farm administrator.

1. In permissions of the User Profile Service Application, I have permissions to connect for Administrator and for Network Service.
2. I tried to use LogonUser to impersonate user as Administrator, but issue is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void FillClaimsForEntity(Uri context, SPClaim entity, List<SPClaim>
claims)
{ 
if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(providerInternalName + ":Invalid 
   Entity");
 if (claims == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(providerInternalName + ":Invalid   
claims collection");

string userId = entity.Value.Split('|')[1];
Dictionary<String, String> userProfileProperties =   

ClaimsHelperClass.GetUserProfileProperties(userId);

 foreach (KeyValuePair<String,String> userProfileProperty in userProfileProperties)
 { 
 claims.Add(CreateClaim(string.Format("  

{0}/{1}",providerClaimType,userProfileProperty.Key),userProfileProperty.Value, 
 claimValueTypeString));

}}

 public static Dictionary<String, String> GetUserProfileProperties(string user)
    {
        Dictionary<String, String> userProfilePropList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {
            ClaimsEntities claimsDb = new ClaimsEntities();
            // This can return multiple Properties for the provider, even if Value is an exact match.  Need to do a secondary filter on Property.
            var userProfileValues = from upp in claimsDb.UserProfileProperties
                                  where upp.UserProfile.NTName == user
                                  select upp;


            foreach (UserProfileProperty upp in userProfileValues)
            {
                userProfilePropList.Add(upp.PropertyName, upp.PropertyVal);
            }

        });

        return userProfilePropList;

    }
```

Comment: Where in your code access to UserProfile from ClaimProvider?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/entdev/archive/2012/02/28/profile-claims.aspx